# How can i use exact functionality for android back button by kivymd

Tags: python, android, kivy, back, kivymd

When i long pressing the back button in last screen of my application then all the screen is being back and close my application. I want to release the back key and screen should be back. How can i use exact functionality for android back button by kivymd? Please someone help me.

Here is my code.

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''


ScreenManager:

    CK1:
    CK2:
    CK3:



<CK1>:
    name: 'C1'
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: [23/255, 200/255, 230/255, 1]



    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Go screen2"
        size_hint_y:.06
        size_hint_x: .95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.80}
        md_bg_color: [147/255, 186/255, 250/255, 1]
        font_size: 20
        text_color: [255/255, 255/255, 0/255, 1]
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'C2'
        on_release: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        on_release: root.manager.transition.duration = .3



<CK2>:
    name: 'C2'
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: [231/255, 231/255, 231/255, 1]



    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Go screen3"
        size_hint_y:.06
        size_hint_x: .95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.80}
        md_bg_color: [147/255, 186/255, 250/255, 1]
        font_size: 20
        text_color: [255/255, 255/255, 0/255, 1]
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'C3'
        on_release: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        on_release: root.manager.transition.duration = .3


<CK3>:
    name: 'C3'
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: [231/255, 231/255, 31/255, 1]



    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "This is screen3"
        size_hint_y:.06
        size_hint_x: .95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.80}
        md_bg_color: [147/255, 186/255, 250/255, 1]
        font_size: 20
        text_color: [255/255, 255/255, 0/255, 1]




'''


class CK1(Screen):
    pass


class CK2(Screen):
    pass


class CK3(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(CK1(name='C1'))
sm.add_widget(CK2(name='C2'))
sm.add_widget(CK3(name='C3'))


class Myscreen(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)




    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keyboard == 27:
            if self.root.current == "C2":
                self.root.current = "C1"
                self.root.transition.direction = 'right'
                return True



            elif self.root.current == "C3":
                self.root.current = "C2"
                self.root.transition.direction = 'right'
                return True
            else:
                return False


Myscreen().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Kivy app closes when the back key is pressed in the andoid. So you need to remove that behaviour first by adding this line in your beginning of your code.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
```

You can change the screen or go back to another screen by implementing this code in your screen class

```
class CK2(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.back_click)

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        Window.unbind(on_keyboard=self.back_click)

    def back_click(self,window, key, keycode, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            """Mention here, what your app should do when user clicks back button in screen C2"""
            print('Going to screen C1')
```

Do this for all of your screen classes